# Mapping Array to Core Data in RestKIt .20

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, object-object-mapping

Iam Trying To map Json To Custom Object Called Place

Managed Object Class Of Place :

```
@interface Place : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * icon;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * place_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * price_level;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * rating;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * vicinity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * reference;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Geometry *geometry;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Json *json;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *opening_hours;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *photos;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *types;
@end
```

and json in this  formate :

```
"results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.870540,
               "lng" : 151.1988150
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png",
         "id" : "c71365287e7606bd21a3311d21fda087830b7813",
         "name" : "Pancakes on the Rocks",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1224,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://plus.google.com/105663944571530352563\"\u003eJoshua Gilmore\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRoAAAAtHLK7ii6I9RN0soDFHF9Zqu1ppyHouUPu-E_BlAP2xlJJLMJrlsBBr3ALzYZ_ysFdgDzJOc-L3NkqQ2FLk5nOAW7LNldTthkSslmbXkXqGbScwCzAwgIj_EyUQlGQjS6d7Ng36nKy_SItlejfeR8zRIQYtT--IxV_d-GfdTcebDjfhoUU7gE_ufZOBxH35EPUtUXbCJk9Gs",
               "width" : 1632
            }
         ],
         "price_level" : 2,
         "rating" : 3.80,
         "reference" : "CoQBcgAAAI_28BshREfmXJ9UKzOLLalhpRaqcW-Wupk1-D2sgkU6ZNe1nsR0zXopB5E-_BGXO1gHxJ1IAe0l-GXzrXj9Dz31crwQ-iwNFLcBRKSGnLmEu_AgKCkfDVZIsgeGrXLNxWLOZ_U8WAZzJu5Uc9tHa9LUF2Rj1MPk9vroGcFjLGWMEhCynlHHTt_P0EZ4wSwwfsumGhQAkqN53-D4ZNjBPEr7qJXZAZMdDg",
         "types" : [ "cafe", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Harbourside Shopping Centre,Darling Harbour/227 & 229-230 Darling Drive, Sydney"
      },
```

the problem when i try to map Photos,types

i have NSManagedObject Class For Photo

```
@interface Photo : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * height;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * width;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * photo_reference;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *html_attributions;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Place *place;
@end
```

i try to map this by :

```
 RKEntityMapping* photosMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Photo class]) inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore];

    [photosMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"height",@"photo_reference",@"html_attributions",@"width"]];

    //Add relationship between place and photos
    [placeMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"photos"
                                                                              toKeyPath:@"photos"
                                                                               withMapping:photosMapping]];
```

but there was exception Or value are photos is nil 
how i can map photos and types any help please

Answer (score 2):

You have two arrays of objects that aren't using KVC key paths, "html_attributions" and "types."  See this RestKit article for more information about mapping in this type of situation: [Mapping values without key paths](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#mapping-values-without-key-paths)

However -- if you have control over the JSON structure, I recommend creating two new Objective C classes, perhaps named `HtmlAttribution` and `Type`, each with one property, create mappings for those classes and set the [relationships](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#relationships) in RestKit. If you can do this and change how your JSON comes through, it will simplify things greatly for you.

Possible new JSON structure for those classes (snippets):

```
 "html_attributions" : [ {"attribution_data":"\u003ca
           href=\"https://plus.google.com/105663944571\u003c/a\u003e"} ],

 "types" : [ {"type_name":"cafe"}, {"type_name":"restaurant"}, 
             {"type_name":"food"}, {"type_name":"establishment"} ],
```